# Makefile issues - fatal error in reader

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, makefile, sparc

I am having some issues with a makefile I am creating for a school project. I am compiling and assembling a C file and a SPARC assembly file (respectively) and linking them. I'm working in a Unix environment. Here is the makefile:

```
proj09.exe: proj09.driver.o proj09.support.o
<tab>gcc -Wall proj09.driver.o proj09.support.o -o proj09.exe

proj09.driver.o: proj09.driver.c /user/cse320/Projects/project09.support.h
<tab>gcc -Wall -c proj09.driver.c /user/cse320/Projects/project09.support.h

proj09.support.o: proj09.support.s
<tab>gcc -Wall proj09.support.s
```

When I try to make it, though, I get a reader error, specifically:

"Fatal error in reader: proj09.makefile, line 2: Unexpected end of line seen"

Now I know that usually this means that something is formatted incorrectly, but I have no idea what it could be in this case. Also, I am not 100% sure that this is the correct code for the makefile (specifically the assembling of my support.s file, and the linking of both files). I apologize if this is a repeat question, I looked through the archives beforehand and couldn't find anything of use. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: I don't see why this would make a difference, but I am using gedit to actually write the code and then transferring the files into SSH for linking.

Comment: Most `make` programs can't handle commands with leading _spaces_, it has to be proper tab.

Comment: Sorry, I should've made that clearer, but I already have tabs in there. It's still not working.

Comment: As a side note, perhaps you didn't mean to compile the header file  `gcc -Wall -c proj09.driver.c /user/cse320/Projects/project09.support.h`. And you're missing a `-c` in `gcc -Wall proj09.support.s`.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to compile the header file as well, though? Otherwise how will the function declarations and such be expressed in the resulting object file?

Comment: No, you're supposed to `#include` the header file. In your case, you accidentally created a precompiled header.

Comment: Okay, thanks, fixed that, although it's still not working :( same error...

Answer (score 2):

As Joachim told you, the lines should be indented by tab, not by spaces, so the second line should look like:

```
[TAB]gcc -Wall proj09.driver.o proj09.support.o -o proj09.exe[NEWLINE]
```

where [TAB] means TAB character.

Also there shouldn't be any spaces after the command. That's why I've put [NEWLINE] char.

Comment: Note that this also means no carriage return characters before the newline (just in case the OP is actually writing the makefile on Windows)

Comment: Nah, writing this in gedit, which to my knowledge puts in all the carriage returns and such (at least, I haven't had a problem with it yet). I don't think it's the editor but obviously I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the spaces and tabs, this doesn't generate an object file, shouldn't even compile (unless it has `main()`):

```
gcc -Wall proj09.support.s
```

You should use `-c` here too:

```
gcc -Wall -c proj09.support.s
```

Note: if you're working on Unix/Linux lose the `.exe`